# C# Gradebook program, reading data from text file

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

I am trying to create a program  which takes data from a text file and uses that text to derive grades for a student. I have 4 students I need to enter, that are stored in a text file, that are in rows as such:

> **ID  || first name || last name  ||  Grades**
>
> 01999911  ||  Bill  ||   Gates  || 27,30,56,60.

I am struggling with capturing the grades of the students, which are in the order of `27 (earned points),30 (possible points),56 (earned points),60 (possible points)`. That string extends for 10 different values for earned points, and 10 values for possible points, in the format of earned points followed by possible points, separated by a coma. After that, I have to take those data points and find the average grade for the student.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to point me in the direction of where I could learn how to code that in, or provide some example code for help. Thanks for any responses.

Comment: What code so you have so far? It sounds like you only need help with the final column of data, is that right? Is the full-stop after the 60 a typo or intentional? Does 'grade' refer to earned/possible?

Comment: I am so far just writing the code for populating the list and creating the getters and setters for the data. I am more of wondering how I am able to separate each variable I need, and tying that data to the student ID.

Comment: I see from your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364778/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array) that you decided to go with commas to separate *everything*. If you look at how my answer processes the `remainder`, including checking what's in there, then your IndexOutOfRangeException problem will go away. And it will highlight which line has the faulty data.

Comment: P.S. You can mark an answer as the accepted answer by pressing the 'tick' to the left of that answer.

Comment: Also the approach in that question uses a pair of arrays rather than the object oriented approach shown here. I really think you should try this approach. Or if you want to stick with an "all commas" approach then add a comment to my answer below, and I will rework my answer below to answer your other question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the full-stop after the 60 in the question is a typo. I'm assuming 'grade' refers to earned/possible.

Since you've said you are currently writing the code to populate the list, I would suggest using the tab character rather than the two pipe character separator. This will make the file a TSV file, and makes the code *slightly* easier to write. (The tab character is represented by `\t` in source code, either in a string, or as a character: `'\t'`.) If you're writing the file yourself, it would help to keep the earned & possible values together using a different separator; for example `27,30;56,60;45,70`(etc). This makes it easier to separate; but I'll show solutions for both.

```
    public class Result
    {
        // This constructor is used by the "different separator for Earned and Possible" approach.
        // Remove this and the default constructor if you don't want to go that way.
        public Result(string line)
        {
            var parts = line.Split(',');
            if (parts.Length != 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Result had {parts.Length} parts: '{line}'");
            }

            EarnedPoints = int.Parse(parts[0]);
            PossiblePoints = int.Parse(parts[1]);
        }

        public Result()
        {
        }

        // Remove this constructor if you go for the approach above.
        public Result(int earnedPoints, int possiblePoints)
        {
            EarnedPoints = earnedPoints;
            PossiblePoints = possiblePoints;
        }

        public int EarnedPoints { get; }
        public int PossiblePoints { get; }
        public double Grade => (double)EarnedPoints / PossiblePoints;
        public string GradeAsPercentage => $"{Grade:P2}";
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public Student(string line)
        {
            var parts = line.Split(new[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            // Could use this instead if you go for TSV:   var parts = line.Split('\t');

            if (parts.Length != 4)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Student had {parts.Length} parts: '{line}'");
            }

            Id = parts[0];
            Forenames = parts[1];
            Surname = parts[2];

            string remainder = parts[3];

            // This is how simple it would be if you used a different separator to group the Earned and Possible together
            //        Results = remainder.Split(';').Select(result => new Result(result)).ToList();
            // Below is an approach where commas are used for everything...
            Results = new List<Result>();
            var items = remainder.Split(',');
            if (items.Length % 2 == 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Odd number of parts in the result: '{line}'");
            }

            int offset = 0;
            while (offset < items.Length)
            {
                int earnedPoints = int.Parse(items[offset++]);
                int possiblePoints = int.Parse(items[offset++]);
                Results.Add(new Result(earnedPoints, possiblePoints));
            }
        }

        public string Id { get; } // Could make this an 'int', in which case use "int.Parse(parts[0])" when setting it, above
        public string Forenames { get; }
        public string Surname { get; }
        public IList<Result> Results { get; }
        public double AverageGrade => Results.Average(r => r.Grade);
        public string AverageGradeAsPercentage => $"{AverageGrade:P2}";
    }
```

then you could just do this to read in the whole file...

```
        var students = File.ReadLines(yourFileName).Skip(1).Select(l => new Student(l));
```

Slight caution: I've gotta go, so rushed a few bits, but hopefully it all works.